# Flatting FOS ElasticaBundle nested fields

Tags: symfony, kibana-4, foselasticabundle

I have FOSElasticaBundle in my Symfony project. I have an entity mapped with ElasticaBundle that has some "simple fields", like

```
mappings:
 createdAt:
    type: "date"
```

and other fields that are IDs (like owner_id) to correlate to other entities, like

```
owner:                   
     type: "nested"
     properties:
          fullname:
          type: string
          index: not_analyzed
```

because I need to have the user fullname searchable with ES/Kibana. This works but it created of course a nested field "owner.fullname" and this kind of fields are not searchable with Kibana (it's since years there are requests about it).
So I'm asking: is there a way to flat out that field so that I have a simple plain string field in ES named "owner_fullname" with no nested data?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer to self.
You can create a method (or use existing where possible) in your class to return informations about related class.
So if you have a User class related to several Address class to store user's addresses, and you want to store in ES the default one, you can create a method "getDefaultAddress" in User class, something like

```
public function getDefaultAddress() {
    return $this->addresses->getDefault()->getFormattedFlatString()
}
```

then map it to a field with elastica Bundle and use the "**property_path:**" descriptor to tell elastica where to get the content for that field.
In this way you have a simple field in ES and not a nested one.
I'm not sure I like this philosophy because you mix up code and external persistence layers, but it works, is clear and easy to maintain especially if you create dedicated methods with same prefix in your class, like **es**GetAddress, **es**GetPlace and so on.